# Passing data to model CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

Thanks to @Mischa for helping me out here.

Answer :

Model :

```
function validate_login($username, $password) {
        $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(17);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? ";
        $loginQ = $this -> db -> query ($sql, array($username));
        $database = $loginQ->row();

        $hash = $database->password;
        if ($bcrypt -> verify($password, $hash)){
            return $loginQ;
        }
    }
```

Controller :

```
function validate_credentials() {
        $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
        $this -> load -> library('bcrypt'); 

        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|alpha_numeric|min_length[4]|max_length[15]');
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[7]|alpha_dash|max_length[20]');

        if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == FALSE) {
            $this -> index();
        } else {
            $this -> load -> library('bcrypt');     
            $this -> load -> model('login_model');

            $username = $this -> input -> post('username');
            $password= $this -> input -> post('password');

            if ($loginQ = $this -> login_model -> validate_login($username, $password)) {
                if ($activated = $this -> login_model -> activated($username)) {
                    $session_array = array('username' => $this -> input -> post('username'), 'loggedin' => TRUE);
                    $this -> session -> set_userdata($session_array);
                    redirect('staff_controller/index');
                } else {
                    $this -> session -> sess_destroy();
                    $this -> load -> view('accessdenied_view');
                    $this -> output -> _display();
                    die();
                }
            } else {
                $this -> index();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What you're trying to do only works when passing data to views.

Comment: But when I print_r($data); in the model I get an array of data (my username and password)

Comment: Yeah, but your not using `$data` in your model. You're using `$username` and `$password`, which are undefined. Either pass `$username` and `$password` *to* your model or use `$data['username']` and `$data['password']` *in* your model. Not a combination of both like you are doing now.

Comment: Why down vote a perfectly legitimate question? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do only works when passing data to views. You just have to pass separate variables to your model. Something like this:

```
function validate_login($username, $password) {
  $bcrypt = new Bcrypt(17);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT ? ";
  $loginQ = $this -> db -> query ($sql, array($username, 1));
  $row = $loginQ->result();

  $hash = $row['password'];
  if ($brcrypt -> verify($password, $hash)){
    return $loginQ;
  }
}
```

Of course this means you also have to change your controller code to pass those variables separately.

Another option would be to use `$date['username']` and `$data['password']` in your model, but I wouldn't recommend that, because it makes your code harder to read.

**Update to make it more clear:**

Controller:

```
$username = $this->input->post('username');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$this->login_model->validate_login($username, $password);
```

Model:

```
function validate_login($username, $password) {
  // Etc.
}
```

Comment: Still nothing, I updated the original post.

Comment: You have to also change your controller. Don't do this: `$this->login_model->validate_login($data)`, but pass username and password to the model separately. I am trying to explain what you're doing wrong. Don't just copy/paste my code. Please try to understand what I am trying to tell you. Also see my comment above.

Comment: I'm still getting errors, original post updated.

Comment: You have to do this instead: `$hash = $database->password;`. By default an object is returned, not an array. If you want an array you have to use `row_array()` instead of `row()`. See: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Comment: I wish I could give you a million up votes. I am so very sorry for the troubles I gave you! Thank you so much for the help. Original post will be updated with your answers.

Comment: You didn't give me any trouble. Glad I could help.

Comment: It also possible to send an array of posts for say a create account form, It would be very tedious to have x amount of $xx = $this->input-Post('xx') in the controller. Is this possible?